# No More than 10 Segment Members in A Batch Call with mailchimp-api-v3

Tags: node.js, npm, mailchimp-api-v3.0, mailchimp-api-v3

I have been using [`mailchimp-api-v3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailchimp-api-v3) in `node js` for some time now and I think it is a great package and so easy to use. However, recently I needed to `GET` Segment Members for several segments using its `.batch()` method.

Unfortunately, only 10 members are returned for each segment even if there are more than 10 members and a `count` query parameter value of more than 10 is specified in the call. With

```
const mc  = require('./mc-config');
const Mailchimp = require('mailchimp-api-v3');
const mailchimp = new Mailchimp(mc.apiKey);
const list_id   = mc.list_id;
```

Each of the following returns more than 10 members, as expected:

```
mailchimp.request({method:'GET',path:`/list/${list_id}/segments/${segment_id}/members`, query: {count: 1000}})....;
//or
mailchimp.get(`/lists/${list_id}/segments/${segment_id}/members?count=1000`)....;
```

However, the following only returns at most 10 segment members, per segment:

```
mailchimp.batch([
    {method:'GET',path:`/lists/${list_id}/segments/${segment_id_1}/members`, query: {count:1000}},
    {method:'GET',path:`/lists/${list_id}/segments/${segment_id_2}/members`, query: {count:1000}},
    {method:'GET',path:`/lists/${list_id}/segments/${segment_id_3}/members`, query: {count:1000}},
    {method:'GET',path:`/lists/${list_id}/segments/${segment_id_4}/members`, query: {count:1000}},
    {method:'GET',path:`/lists/${list_id}/segments/${segment_id_5}/members`, query: {count:1000}}
])....;
```

I thought that perhaps `query` parameters were being ingnored altogether but when I added the following parameters I got more members returned for segments which had less than 10 members:

```
.... include_cleaned:true, include_unsubscribed:true ....
```

Has anybody else experienced this issue? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Promise.all()` seems to work just fine, a pity though that I can use `.batch()`:

```
(async () => {
    try {
        const segments = [segment_id1, segment_id2, segment_id3, segment_id4];
        const members = await Promise.all(
            segments.map(tag => mailchimp.get(`/lists/${list_id}/segments/${tag}/members?count=1000`))
        );
        //see how many members are returned
        console.log( members.map(m => m.members.length) );
    } catch( err ) {
        console.log( err );
    } finally {
        console.log( 'All done' );
    }
})();
```

For each segment/tag that had more than 10 members, all the members were returned (upto 1000).